# Событие для IntentFilter

Tags: android

Необходимо событие, которое срабатывает при переключении устройства в режим точки доступа.

Comment: Думаю, что такого нет... Можно как-то попытаться, например, слущать событие подключения к вайфай сети, и по ее конфигурации определить, в каком режиме работает дивйс.

Answer (score 1):

Половите событие: [CONNECTIVITY_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)

Action: **android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE**

Конкретная расшифровка приходит в виде EXTRA